# which PSU cable goes where on the MB please

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

Sorry about the newb post, but I'm completely newbie at modular PSUs and having trouble installing mine

I bought this PSU: be quiet! Straight Power 11 Platinum 750W

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B083SVGSP3?tag=pcp0f-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1

MANUAL:

https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/B1nARER1k-S.pdf

My PSU is the one on the right in the picture on page 1 of the manual

And this MB: Asus TUF GAMING Z790

https://www.amazon.co.uk/ASUS-GAMING-Z790-PLUS-Intel-Wi-Fi/dp/B0BPHCPSCM/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=Asus+TUF+GAMING+Z790-PLUS+WIFI+ATX+LGA1700+Motherboard+Asus+TUF+GAMING+Z790&qid=1688204764&sr=8-1

1. Problem: main power cable

1.1. it's straighforward where it plugs in the MB at one end

1.2. the other end in the PSU is a problem: it's separated into a 20 pin entry, and a 8 pin entry. The PSU has the 20 pin entry, and right underneath another 8 pin entry, both marked as "MB". Since this design is pretty counterintuitive, I don't know whether I should also connect the 8 pin entry underneath, or leave it unplugged. Manual is useless on both pieces of hardware on this matter. This video shows something similar, but refers to 24 pins, while I got 28:

View: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXaLc9AYIcg

, so I still don't know for sure

2. Problem: secondary (CPU?) power cable. MB must take 2 x 8 pin connectors according to manual

2.1. Got 2 cables in the kit:

2.1.a. cable with 10 pins (middle ones missing actually) which connects to the only 10 pin slot in PSU. I guess that's it?

2.1.a.1 the other end same cable separates into a 1 x 8 pin connector named P8, and another 2x4 pin separated but bundled closeby, and named CPU1 - P4, CPU2 - P8. The only PSU slot also is named P8/P4. I have no idea which of the 2 motherboard 8 pin connector takes which end from these. The motherboard manual doesn't show these. These cable connectors also have clamps for the motherboard, which don't correspond to anything I can see on the motherboard slot, although I can push them in I think if I try

Motherboard manual:

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1700/TUF_GAMING_Z790-PLUS_WIFI/E21279_TUF_GAMING_Z790-PLUS_WIFI_UM_WEB.pdf?model=TUF%20GAMING%20Z790-PLUS%20WIFI

2.1.b. cable with 10 pins at one end as the other, but only 2x4pins ending at the other, so I guess this is not it since the motherboard manuals sais I must connect 2 of 8 pins each. Again, CPU1 - P4, CPU2 - P8 is written on the 2x4 pins

3. The rest are 2 x VGA cables of 12 pins to 2x8 pins, which I guess connect to the GPU, and storage device and such which seem pretty straightforward, and have straighforward slots for them in the PSU

Comment: PCs are designed to the cables only fit the correct sockets & can't be fit into an incorrect one. If your plug has more pins than your socket, then it will either be splittable  or it will fit with some pins hanging over the edge. Once you've used up all the ones that fit, what you're left with you need to identify adaptors for. VGA is not a power connector type, it's a video connector type.

Comment: Nope, I can fit both 8 and 4+4 on the motherboard. Question is whether this is correct, or whether I should get a specialized PSU for this

Comment: @AngryPidgeon - You need to purchase an ATX 3.0 power supply.

Answer (score 0):

The MB manual, on page 2-14, shows connecting **both** 8-pin connectors. However, your PS appears to have only one MB 8-pin connector. You may be able to buy a splitter cable such as [this at Amazon US](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082KF7Z35). However, the fact that the MB has two connectors indicates that it draws a lot of current on the +12 volt bus and your power supply may not be able to supply this.

You would be better off returning the PS and finding one with two 8-pin MB (“ATX_12V”) connectors.

Comment: Those 8-pin connectors are not EPS connectors. They are the ATX_12V connectors, which is part of the ATX 3.0 standard.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks - corrected.